# How to select text from a scanned image before extracting?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I want to extracted the selected text from image.

What I am doing right now.

**Step 1:** Capture the image using camera.

**Step 2:** Creating cgImage of captured image as following

```swift
     guard let cgImage = caputuredImage.cgImage else { return }
```

**Step 3:** Processing above image in the following Vision framework code snippet:

```swift
        //Hanlder
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage, options: [:])
        
        //Request
        let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error in
            guard let observation = request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation], error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            let text = observation.compactMap({
                $0.topCandidates(1).first?.string
            }).joined(separator: " ")
           
            print(text) // here I got the extracted text from image.
            
            self.extractedTextView.text = text
        }
        
        //Process Request
        do {
            try handler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            
            Debug.log(message: "Failed to perform request with error: ", variable: error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

I have got the extracted text, but I don't want like above steps.

**What I want now is:** 
**Step 1:** Capture picture from camera of some textbook page. 
**Step 2:** Select portion of text from that picture, and then only that selected text should be extracted like we do in google lens.

An example question of stack overflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197028/how-do-i-select-text-from-a-scanned-photo), but this is in flutter. I want that in swift or in objective c.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Tip: when you post a question, don't say *"like we do in [some other app]"* or *"like some other code in some other answer"*. Describe exactly what you want to do. If you're talking about allowing the user to drag to draw a rect around the recognized text, then the `VNRecognizedTextObservation` object has a `.boundingBox` property (coordinates in percentages) that you can use.

Comment: Hey man, I am new here. Thanks for your tip and answer. I will check how to use that. Thanks.

Comment: @Aafaq Please take a [tour] and check out [ask] for tips how to write a good question.

Comment: Okay @koen thanks!